# Can anyone see why the bootstrap tabs are not working inside my modal?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot get tabs to work on the inside of my modal no matter what I do. If it matters the modal is within a ng-repeat with angularJS and the modal id is being called dynamically

```
    <!--======== Trigger ========-->
    <a data-toggle="modal" href='#{{faIcon.iconSelect}}'>Trigger Modal</a>


    <!--======== modal ========-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="{{faIcon.iconSelect}}">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-fw">{{faIcon.theIcon}}</i>{{faIcon.name}}</h4>
          </div>





          <div class="modal-body">
            <h1><i class="fa fa-fw">{{faIcon.theIcon}}</i></h1>

             <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
                <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>

              </ul>

              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">1</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="2">2</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="3">3</div>

              </div>

          </div>






          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

            <input ng-copy="copied=true" ng-init="copied=false; value='copy me'" ng-model="value">opied: {{copied}}

          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <!--======== modal ========-->
```

Am i missing an init code or something

Comment: It's working on Bootply http://www.bootply.com/nIa0DkgtF7

Comment: Yes you are right. So I guess i am having an angular problem... The g1 id for the modal is being called with a dynamic code generated by the corrisponding list item and that is when the tabs stop loading the content BUT the tab active states work... See updated code

Answer (score 1):

according to my tests it seems that you don't have any problems with the code so the problem is probably  on another line of your code.

The easiest but most common things that make this kind of thing happen is that you probably forgat to close some tag..